# Convert array of key value object to object of the key values (ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a list of objects that have key attribute and value attribute.

I would like to convert it to an object that contains attributes named as keys with the values.

Example will make it clearer...

This

```
[{
    :key => "key1",
    :value => "value1"
  }, {
    :key => "key2",
    :value => "value2"
}]
```

Should become like this:

```
{
  :key1 => "value1"
  :key2 => "value2"
}
```

I'm sure there is one line to make it happen
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D), [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
a = [{
    :key => "key1",
    :value => "value1"
  }, {
    :key => "key2",
    :value => "value2"
}]

Hash[a.map { |h| [h[:key], h[:value]] }]
# => {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}

Hash[a.map { |h| h.values_at(:key, :value) }]
# => {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}

Hash[a.map { |h| [h[:key].to_sym, h[:value]] }]
# => {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}

a.each_with_object({}) {|h,g| g.update({h[:key].to_sym => h[:value]}) }
# => {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```

Comment: Here's another, ft: `a.each_with_object({}) {|h,g| g.update {h[:key].to_sym => h[:value]}`. +1

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[array.map(&:values)]
#=> {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2"}
```

Comment: The OP wants the new keys to be symbols.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, ha, it won't be so elegant with symbolizing keys :)

Comment: That was my suspicion. From an educational viewpoint, I think bending the question a little is OK when it permits an interesting solution. Really like your specs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to promote the `to_h` a bit:

```
[{
    :key => "key1",
    :value => "value1"
  }, {
    :key => "key2",
    :value => "value2"
}].map(&:values).map{|k,v| [k.to_sym,v]}.to_h

# => {:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```